# No matching function for call to

Tags: c++

Написал шаблон функции, описал функцию, но компилятор выдает мне такую ошибку:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘firstNeg(int [2][2], int,
>   int)’

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<class T> T firstNeg(T array, T dim2, T curDim) {
    for (int i = curDim; array[i]; i += dim2) {
        if (array[i] < 0)
            return array[i];
    }
    return 0;
}

int firstNeg(int* array, int dim2, int curDim);

/*int firstNeg(int* array, int dim2, int curDim) {
    for (int i = curDim; array[i]; i += dim2) {
        if (array[i] < 0)
            return array[i];
    }
    return 0;
}*/

main() {
    int dim2 = 2;
    int array[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {-1, -2} };
    // вызов функции с указателем
    int i = firstNeg(array, 2, 0);
    printf("%i \n", i);
}
```

В чем заключается ошибка?

Comment: Вы бы лучше описали, **что** должна делать функция. Т.к. можно предложить решение, которое будет компилироваться, но не факт, что оно Вам подойдет.

Comment: И как это должно было работать? В шаблоне один и тот же тип `T` указан для всех трех параметров - т.е. шаблон уходит из рассмотрения сразу. Остается только нешаблонная версия функции, но у нее первый параметр `int *`, т.е. с двухмерным массивом не совместим никак. Вот и все.

Comment: @Alex   Опишите в вопросе, что должна делать функция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать в шаблонную функци массив можно двумя способами:

**1) Передача по ссылке:**

```
template<class T, std::size_t s1, std::size_t s2>
void func(T(& name)[s1][s2])
{
    std::cout << "Array by reference" << std::endl;
    std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << name[0][0] << " " << name[s1 - 1][s2 - 1] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int mas[2][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5} };
    func(mas);
}
```

**2) Передача по указателю:**

```
template<class T, std::size_t s1, std::size_t s2>
void func2(T(*name)[s1][s2])
{
    std::cout << "Array by pointer" << std::endl;
    std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*name)[0][0] << " " << (*name)[s1 - 1][s2 - 1] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int mas[2][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5} };
    func2(&mas);
}
```

В принципе можно передавать массив как просто указатель и потом кастовать к типу массива или двойному указателю, но не думаю что это то что Вам нужно, да и, как по мне, не очень это правильно.

Comment: Спасибо, по вашему примеру разобрался!

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот например,

```
T firstNeg(T array, T dim2, T curDim)
```

пусть `T` - `int`. Т.е. `array` - просто число. И что должно собой представлять `array[i]`? :)

Но это к самой функции. Вот вы ей передаете `firstNeg(array, 2, 0);`

Но ведь у вас по шаблону судя, типы `array`, 2 и 0 должны быть одинаковы. Но разве ваш `array` - это `int`?

Всё понятно? или разжевывать дальше?

Comment: За с++ второй день, грубо говоря, поэтому такие вопросы и возникают) мне в функцию надо передать указатель на массив, количество столбцов и номер нужного мне столбца. Как мне тогда пометить в шаблоне, что мне нужно передать именно указатель на массив?

Comment: @kff т.е получается template<class T> T firstNeg(T *array, int dim2, int curDim) ?

Comment: @kff хм, все равно компилятор ругается.. no matching function for call to ‘firstNeg(int [2][2], int, int)’

Comment: Если вы второй день за C++, то, может, не стоит пока что мучиться с шаблонами? Впрочем... **если вы знаете размеры во время компиляции**, то действительно можно шаблоном - `template<class T, int Dim1, int Dim2> firstNeg(T (&array)[Dim1][Dim2])`...

Comment: @Harry я бы с радостью, но так велят нам лабораторные работы..

Comment: Для вас проще всего - если знаете размеры при компиляции - `template<class T, int Dim1, int Dim2> firstNeg(T (&array)[Dim1][Dim2])`. Но в теле функции у вас все равно ерунда написана... Попробуйте для начала написать не шаблон, а просто функцию, а уж потом переделывайте в шаблон.

Comment: @Harry int firstNeg(int* array, int dim2, int curDim) {
 for (int i = curDim; array[i]; i += dim2) {
  if (array[i] < 0)
   return array[i];
 }
 return 0;
} << вот функция, и она, в целом, работала. А что с ней не так?

Comment: Все так, разве что она у вас не скомпилируется :) Вы же передаете в нее не `int*`, а `int[2][2]`. И потом, что она должна делать? Вы уверены, что она работает так, как вы того хотите? у меня большие сомнения... Проверьте ее на массиве `int array[2][2] = { {1, -2}, {1, -2} };`